# Add release note to testflight builds from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, cicd, release-notes

I want to add release notes to testflight build from Xcode. Below is a tutorial to tell how to do that. but this approach is not working for me. Does anyone have an idea or another way to do it?
https://blog.codemagic.io/upload-release-notes-to-testflight/

Comment: Are you using the Codemagic platform? Need more details from your scenario.

Comment: just i want to add automatically release notes to testflight builds, at the moment I'm doing it manually from testflight